# crystal report datetime field does not show but has value c#

Tags: c#, datetime, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in which I used datasets to display values. The data set is filled from view(sql view) retrieved in data connection (table adapter, data table)_. All fields are displaying except for the one field which is datetime. I have tried every possible way but not working. I am at my wits end.

1. I tried converting it to string both in sql itself in view design
   and in dataset.
2. I casted it using ToText() and put it in formula but keeps returning
   error 'field not known'. I was thinking I might have dropped the field but I already re added the dataset, data table and adapter and made sure I clicked the "verify database" and the field is there!
3. I tried debugging the code to make sure the value is being pulled,
   and yes it is.
4. I "preview data" the datatable in dataset by right clicking it and
   clicking preview data and yes it shows the field has value. All
   fields are displaying
5. I tried making the field in the dataset properties as string(before
   I changed datetime type to string)

But why is it not showing in the report itself. :(. any idea or other suggestion I can try to make it show?

```
public void loadReport(bool loadAll)
    {

      AirDataAccess ada = new AirDataAccess();

     List<AirData> alist= ada.GetRowLogAllView();


            ReportUrl = @"~\Reports\RawLogData.rpt";
            reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(ReportUrl));

                          reportDocument.SetDataSource(alist);


            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;



    }
```

Comment: Can you check if you are able to see that field in crystal report designer? I mean without running report through gui.

Comment: yes I can see it during main report preview  with out running. it displays.

Comment: I added a new field of date time in the report and it does not show also. BUt this time a string data type also does not show. others are working fine. this is getting random, i do not know anymore. I'vre tried making all nullable to not null just in case it is the culprit but still the same. :(

Comment: I already solved it. stupid stupid me..my model name and database field names are spelled differently. In the view/db it is dateAir, while my model says dateAired..I almost banged my head geeesh!